# Will old editions of Blood Bowl be able to play with people who has Chaos Edition?

Tags: blood-bowl

I have the Legendary version of the game and I know some who have a league where they play Chaos Edition, I would like to know if I have to upgrade my edition to play with them or if I can play with my edition and just not have access to the new teams.

So if you have the Original, Dark Elves or Legendary version of the game can you then play with a person who has the Chaos Edition of the game?

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: At a guess, the downvote may be someone feeling that not trying before asking is a lack of research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Players with the Legendary Edition can play with those with Chaos edition, though you won't have access to the additional teams/races available in the newer edition.

Those with only the Original or Dark Elves edition are out of luck, however, from what I can gather with casual experimentation.